# problem in retriving multiple checkbox values

Tags: javascript, jsp

I am unable to access the values of checkboxes i select.
Here is my code which i tried.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="<%= "gname_" + in.intValue() %>" name="chkBox" onclick='chkboxSelect(localArrGroupNames[<%=in.intValue() %>],<%= "gname_" + in.intValue() %>)'>



JS code:  
function chkboxSelect( chkBoxValue, id){  
      var i=0;  
    if(id.checked)  {  
       var selected;  
       alert("id:  " + chkBoxValue + i);  
       selected[i] = chkBoxValue;  
       i++;  
    }  

    }
```

I get only one value in my alert though I select more than one value.
For example if i select red, blue, green, After I select each, I get only one in my alert.
Please help me . Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried setting 'chkBoxValue=null;' at the end? May be you can make sure that the checkbox is returning the values after first selection.

Answer (score 0):

If all checkboxes have the same name *chkBox*

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
<script>
  function getValues(){
        var cbs    = document.getElementsByName('chkBox');
        var result = '';

        for(var i=0; i<cbs.length; i++) {
         if(cbs[i].checked ) result += (result.length > 0 ? "," : "") + cbs[i].value;
        }

        alert(result);
        return result;
     }
</script>
</head>

<body>  
 <input type="checkbox" id="gname_1" name="chkBox" onclick='getValues();' value='red'>Red<br>
 <input type="checkbox" id="gname_2" name="chkBox" onclick='getValues();' value='green'>Green<br>
 <input type="checkbox" id="gname_3" name="chkBox" onclick='getValues();' value='blue'>Blue<br>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I get on, on, undefined, on, undefined, on

Comment: I have updated the code. You need add a value to each checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you use multiple checkboxes with the same name, your code shoud be like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkBox[]" value="red">
<input type="checkbox" name="chkBox[]" value="green">
<input type="checkbox" name="chkBox[]" value="blue">
```

if you submit the form, you will get an array... ($_POST['chkBox'][0])

Comment: Note that this will work in PHP, but OP has Java as a server side logic. And there it may work in different way.

Comment: OP is not using PHP. OP is using JSP. JSP does not require those silly brackets like as PHP. PHP requires this special bracked suffix syntax because it would otherwise return `String` with 1st value instead of `String[]` with all values.